# Turning JSON into a Map in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

If i want a map to read its data from a json file, I first have to make the json file's content a javascript object, which the map cannot read because it is not iterable. Therefore, I was recommended a method to turn the javascript object into an array, which is iterable, with a function before making it a map. But the problem is, the output i get is always *Map(0) {}*, an empty map:

```
const fs = require('fs');

//function turning the js object into an array
function objToArr (object) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }
}

//object with the json file's content
var object = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('file.json', 'utf-8')

const map = new Map (objToArr(object))

console.log(map)

//Output: Map(0) {}
```

The code has no problem reading the json file, if i write this...

```
console.log(objToMap(object))
//output: Key: value1, value2, value3...
```

...it gives me the correct output, but unfortunately, it won't do the same if I want to use it as a map.

Is there any kind of way to resolve this problem?

Comment: `objToArr` function doesnt `return` anything

Comment: Share the json sample

Comment: `const map = new Map (Object.entries(object))`

Comment: You don't need to `JSON.parse` &  `fs.readFileSync`. You can just do `const obj = require('./file.json')` and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Object.entries()` to feed it:

```
const myMap = new Map(Object.entries(myObj));
```